# Firebase PubSub Emulator not recieving messages

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, firebase-tools

I'm trying to get the firebase emulator, to trigger cloud functions using pubsub publishing.
The basic setup works outside of the cloud functions.
When trying to connect the cloud function, no message ever appears.

I have the feeling, that I doing something fundamentally wrong.

Publish code:

```
import { PubSub, Topic } from '@google-cloud/pubsub'; 
const topicName = 'MyTopic';
const [taskTopic] = await pubsub.createTopic(topicName);
await this.taskTopic.publish(Buffer.from(msg));
```

"Manual" Subscription: works

```
 [subscription] = await this.renderTaskTopic.createSubscription(subscriptionName);
 subscription.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log('Received message:', message.data.toString());
    process.exit(0);
 });
```

Subscription using cloud function: never gets called in the emulator

```
export const subscribeToRenderTask = functions.pubsub.topic(topicName)
    .onPublish(async (message: functions.pubsub.Message) => {
        console.log('subscribeToRenderTask', message.data);
     }
```

The emalutor setup seems fine

```
 functions: The Firebase Authentication emulator is not running, so calls to Firebase Authentication will affect production.
✔  functions[convert]: http function initialized (http://0.0.0.0:5001/puredio-development/europe-west3/convert).
✔  functions[subscribeToRenderTask]: pubsub function initialized.

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://0.0.0.0:8081                  │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────┬────────────────┬───────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator  │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI           │
├───────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions │ 0.0.0.0:5001   │ http://0.0.0.0:8081/functions │
├───────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────────────────┤
│ Firestore │ 0.0.0.0:8080   │ http://0.0.0.0:8081/firestore │
├───────────┼────────────────┼───────────────────────────────┤
│ Pub/Sub   │ 127.0.0.1:8085 │ n/a                           │
└───────────┴────────────────┴───────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at 127.0.0.1:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTFM: I needed to set the following env vars so that my tests could actually find the pub sub emulator

```
export PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST = 'localhost:8085'
export PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID = 'my-project'
```

Comment: Did you have to setup these variables on while running the tests? I have a setup where I have API's triggering a message to pub-sub topic and cloud function subscribing to it. On my integration tests (mocha-chai) I am able to call the API and I can also see the log stating that message published to the topic. However, my cloud function subscription is not triggered by this message.

Comment: Oops, I was setting these variables on test project and my API was all along pushing the messages to real pub-sub. I configured these on my actual API and subsequently the messages started getting pushed to my emulator